# How to not clear textarea value when searching with Javascript onsearch Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsearch.asp

What I want is the text that I searched with to stay in the textarea or at least get back to the textarea, not disappear because I click the enter button.

I understand that it clears the text because in the link they describe the function like this: "The onsearch event occurs when a user presses the "ENTER" key or clicks the "x" button in an  element with type="search".

So it acts as if I click the x button, although, there must be a way to get the text back there after?

This is my current code html code

```
 <form> <input type="search" name="search" id="searchid" onsearch="OnSearch(this)"/> </form>
```

This is my javasript/jquery

```
function OnSearch(input) {
    alert("The current value of the search field is " + input.value);
    $("#searchid").val(input.value);
}
```

What happens now is that it correctly alerts the value the textarea is holding, although it wont add back the textarea value.

EDIT: It seems like the page reloads, how can i insert code that runs after page reload?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Does that happen to be in a form? If so it might be reloading the page acting as a submit button. Make to to prevent it's default behavior with `e.preventDefault` or just `return false` (or remove the form).

Comment: Yes its in a form, ye it seems to be reloading , not sure how to deny the reload tho, i tried event.preventDefault(); in the function, is that what u meant? (cant remove the form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have an alternative. Since you cannot avoid the clear functionality you can store the text each time `keypressed` in a global variable and if `x` is pressed retain the value in textbox. Below is the code:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/d2qfzvuo/)**

```
var text=""; 
function OnSearch(input) {
    if(input.value == "") {
          $("#searchid").val(text);
    }
    else {
         alert("You searched for " + input.value);
    }
}

$(document).on('keyup','#searchid', function (e) {
    text=$(this).val();
    console.log(text);
});
```

**UPDATE**

if your html is inside the form you can do as below:

Check in `document.ready` if it already had a text and if yes set it!!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   if(localStorage.getItem("text")!="")
   {
        $("#searchid").val(localStorage.getItem("text"));
   }
});


function OnSearch(input) {
    if(input.value == "") {
          $("#searchid").val(localStorage.getItem("text"));
    }
    else {
         alert("You searched for " + input.value);
    }
}

$(document).on('keyup','#searchid', function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem("text",$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: It seems however that the page reloads and is the reason for me losing the value, this works perfectly when i dont have the html inside of a form, but i need to have it in a form, going to edit my question with that! Do you know how it can be done when the html is inside of a form?

Comment: @mattias.. Updated the answer!! Kindly check and let me know!! :)

Comment: copied and tried, text is still gone after reload unfortunately!

Comment: It works! thank you!! I had to switch the script place to inside the head instead and it worked

Comment: Oh yea.. Forgot to mention that part. Anyways glad it worked. Happy coding!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you to display the alert dialog symbol as that:

HTML:

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="searchid"/>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("searchid").onsearch = function() {yourfunctionname()};
/* Put this before the below function or in the top of the document */
function yourfunctionname(){
  var x = document.getElementById("searchid").value;
  alert("The current value of the search field is "+x);
  /* Or do what ever you wish */
}
/*Remember to replace the yourfunctionname with your function's name */
```

OR If it is in a form try this:

Your form should look like this:

```
<form method="/* method */" action="/* action */" onSubmit="yourfunctionname()">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="searchid"/>
  /* Rest of your form*/
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("searchid").value = localStorage.getItem("saved");
document.getElementById("searchid").onsearch = function() {yourfunctionname()};
/* Put this before the below function or in the top of the document */
function yourfunctionname(){
  var x = document.getElementById("searchid").value;
  alert("The current value of the search field is "+x);
  /* Or do what ever you wish */
  /* The below code does the trick*/
  localStorage.setItem("saved", x);
  location.reload();
  return false;     
}
/* Remember to replace the yourfunctionname with your function's name */
```

If you are having a different function to submit the form then replace your form's onsubmit attribute with that function's name and a word "return" before it's name and add the below javascript inside that function.

```
var x = document.getElementById("searchid").value
localStorage.setItem("saved", x);
location.reload();
return false;
```

If you wanted something else then please comment.

Please accept as if it solves your problem.
And thanks...

Lastly for more just comment